# Adicionar código na Pasta de Trabalho utilizando uma macro

Tags: vba, diretório

Tenho um código que registra quem imprime o documento, mas tenho uns mil documentos e tenho que inserir o código, eu já tenho o código de colocar módulos, mas preciso de um para colocar na Pasta de Trabalho pra funcionar quando imprime, mas não encontro como.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)

On Error Resume Next

Dim revisão As Integer
revisão = 0
Dim vUsuario As String, vMaquina As String
vUsuario = deUSUARIO()
vMaquina = deMAQUINA()

Open "\\CAMINHO\DO\ARQUIVO\" & Right(Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, 8), 4) & ".txt" For Input As #1

Line_ = 0

Do Until EOF(1)

    Line Input #1, Text

    Line_ = Line_ + 1

    If Text = "" Then

        Exit Do

    End If

    revisão = Left(Text, 3)

Loop

Close #1

Open "\\CAMINHO\DO\ARQUIVO\" & Right(Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, 8), 4) & ".txt" For Append As #2

If revisão <= 9 Then

    Print #2, "0" & (revisão + 1) & " - O usuário: " & vUsuario & " - " & "pela Máquina: " & vMaquina & " - " & "Imprimiu este documento dia: " & Now

Else

    If revisão >= 10 Then

        Print #2, (revisão + 1) & " - O usuário: " & vUsuario & " - " & "pela Máquina: " & vMaquina & " - " & "Imprimiu este documento dia: " & Now

    End If

End If

Close #2

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei a resposta.

```
Set WECodeMod2 = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("EstaPasta_de_trabalho").CodeModule

Open "c:\CAMINHO\DO\ARQUIVO.txt" For Input As #2

  Line_1 = 0

  Do Until EOF(2)

    Line Input #2, text_1

    Line_1 = Line_1 + 1

    WECodeMod2.InsertLines Line_1, text_1

  Loop

Close #2
```